# How to parse pubDate from rss in flutter?

Tags: datetime, flutter, rss, pubdate

I am trying to parse pubDate from rss into DateTime object.

```
String parseFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
this.pubDate = new DateFormat(parseFormat).parse(json['pubDate']);
```

This throws error

> Trying to read ddd from Thu, 14 May 2020 09:40:15 EST at position 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to

```
String parseFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
this.pubDate = new DateFormat(parseFormat).parse(json['pubDate']);
```

from the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html).